# How can I update a widget according to a certain value that comes from a seperate thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

My GUI application has multiple screens (3) while each includes certain Text widgets that the user can change (I based this multiple screens GUI according to a well known, in stackoverflow, solution). After filling a certain screen's fields the user can "Burn" these values to a certain HW. In order to be able to "Burn" to the HW I initiate a Telnet session to the HW (the IP is hard coded) immediately after the app is running.

Each of the frames shows the status bar which I want to update with the current status of the Telnet connection to the HW. For the purpose of the maintaining the Telnet connection I have used a separate thread. And I also used a queue in order to update with the current status.

I was able to update, by a simple print to the console, when the Telnet session status was changed. I am also able to recover the Telnet session if it was disconnected for any good (or bad) reason.

My problem is that I am not able to update the status bar (status label) with the current status. In the code below you can see that I have tried to generate an event upon status change. But, it didn't do the work. How can I update the status bar with the actual status ?

**After editing**

(I made a great effort and removed more than 200 lines of code):

```
from tkinter import font, ttk
import tkinter as tk
from re import match

import telnetlib
import threading
import queue

import time

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
Current_PN = '123456789'    # This global ver is used for the purpose of automatic PN fill

HOST = '10.0.1.235'
PORT = 23

telnet_session = None       # After I create the Telnet session I will keep track with this variable
connected = False

class BurningApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.title('Burning App')  #handling the application's Window title

        w = 1000    # Windows width
        h = 600     # Windows height

        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()       # Screen resolution width
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()     # Screen resolution height

        # w = ws * 0.8    # Fit the GUI width to 80% percent of the screen
        # h = hs * 0.8    # Fit the GUI height to 80% percent of the screen

        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)      # X coordinate for the purpose of GUI placement
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)      # X coordinate for the purpose of GUI placement



        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d'%(w,h,x,y))

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainScreen, FirstScreen, SecondScreen):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainScreen)

        # Start the Telnet session
        self.connect_to_uut()

        # Create the queue that will hold the status
        self.status_queue = queue.Queue()

        # Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O
        self.running = 1    # True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread)
        self.thread.start()

        # Start the periodic call in the GUI to check if the queue contains
        # anything
        self.periodicCall()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        '''
        This function is being used in order to raise a frame on demand
        '''
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


    def connect_to_uut(self, Retry=5):
        '''
        This functions is used for the purpose of connecting to the UUT
        '''
        global telnet_session
        global connected

        for _ in range(Retry):
            try:
                telnet_session = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, timeout=5)
                connected = True
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                break
            except:
                connected = False
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                continue


    def periodicCall(self):
        """
        Check every 10 sec if there is something new in the queue.
        This is actually Telnet connection status check
        """
        self.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            # This is the brutal stop of the system. You may want to do
            # some cleanup before actually shutting it down.
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        self.after(10000, self.periodicCall)


    def processIncoming(self):
        """
        Handle all the messages currently in the queue (if any).
        """
#         global connected

        while self.status_queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.status_queue.get(0)
                # Check contents of message and do what it says
                # As a test, I simply print it
                print(msg)
#                 if not connected:
#                     self.connect_to_uut()
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def workerThread(self):
        """
        This is where we handle the asynchronous I/O.
        """
        global telnet_session
        global connected

        while self.running:
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                telnet_session.sock.send(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.NOP)
                connected = True
                msg = 'Connected'
            except:
                connected = False
                msg = 'Disconnected'       #The Actual Status of the Telnet session
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                if not connected:
                    self.connect_to_uut()

            self.status_queue.put(msg)



class MainScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=10, weight='bold')

        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                             width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(pady=8)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                             width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button2.pack(pady=8)

        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 3",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                             width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button3.pack(pady=8)

        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 4",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(SecondScreen),
                            width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5) 
        self.button4.pack(pady=8)

        self.button5 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM FAN ",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                            width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5) 
        self.button5.pack(pady=8)

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg="black")        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")

class FirstScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.valid_string_color = "springgreen3"
        self.invalid_string_color = "red2"

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Lable_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=10, weight='bold')

        self.SN_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="Serial Number", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.SN_Label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.SN_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.SN_field.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.PN_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="Part Number", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.PN_Label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.PN_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.PN_field.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.HwVer_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="HW Version", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.HwVer_Label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.HwVer_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.HwVer_field.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.main_frame, text="Burn",
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=(20,0))

        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg='black')        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")
        self.status.bind("<<StatusChange>>", self.statuschange)     # React to the status change event and change the status label accordingly

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainScreen),
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(side="bottom", pady=(0,20))


    def statuschange(self):
        global connected

        if connected:
            self.my_string_var.set('Connected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_ConnectedStyle, fg='springgreen3')
        else:
            self.my_string_var.set('Disonnected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_DisconnectedStyle, fg='red2')

class SecondScreen(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.valid_string_color = "springgreen3"
        self.invalid_string_color = "red2"

        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Lable_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=5, weight='bold')

        self.SN_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="Serial Number", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.SN_Label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.SN_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.SN_field.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.PN_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="Part Number", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.PN_Label.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.PN_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.PN_field.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.HwVer_Label = tk.Label(self.main_frame, text="HW Version", font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.HwVer_Label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)     # Y axis padding was added only to the label. This padding effects the whole line

        self.HwVer_field = tk.Text(self.main_frame, height=1, width=30, font=self.Lable_Font_Style1)
        self.HwVer_field.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.main_frame, text="Burn",
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, pady=(20,0))

        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg="black")        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")
        self.status.bind("<<StatusChange>>", self.statuschange)     # React to the status change event and change the status label accordingly

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainScreen),
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(side="bottom", pady=(0,20))


    def statuschange(self):
        global connected

        if connected:
            self.my_string_var.set('Connected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_ConnectedStyle, fg='springgreen3')
        else:
            self.my_string_var.set('Disonnected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_DisconnectedStyle, fg='red2')


def main():
    app = BurningApp()        
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

By the way, I know that I am missing the method that should update the status bar in the MainScreen Class

As I promised here is the most reduced code. I left some "fraems", just to be able to see that each frame shows the right status, and I removed the irrelevant fields

```
from tkinter import font, ttk
import tkinter as tk
from re import match

import telnetlib
import threading
import queue

import time

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
Current_PN = '123456789'    # This global ver is used for the purpose of automatic PN fill

HOST = '10.0.1.235'
PORT = 23

telnet_session = None       # After I create the Telnet session I will keep track with this variable
connected = False

class BurningApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.title('Burning App')  #handling the application's Window title

        w = 1000    # Windows width
        h = 600     # Windows height

        ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()       # Screen resolution width
        hs = self.winfo_screenheight()     # Screen resolution height

        # w = ws * 0.8    # Fit the GUI width to 80% percent of the screen
        # h = hs * 0.8    # Fit the GUI height to 80% percent of the screen

        x = (ws/2) - (w/2)      # X coordinate for the purpose of GUI placement
        y = (hs/2) - (h/2)      # X coordinate for the purpose of GUI placement



        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d'%(w,h,x,y))

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainScreen, FirstScreen, SecondScreen):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainScreen)

        # Start the Telnet session
        self.connect_to_uut()

        # Create the queue that will hold the status
        self.status_queue = queue.Queue()

        # Set up the thread to do asynchronous I/O
        self.running = 1    # True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread)
        self.thread.start()

        # Start the periodic call in the GUI to check if the queue contains
        # anything
        self.periodicCall()

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        '''
        This function is being used in order to raise a frame on demand
        '''
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


    def connect_to_uut(self, Retry=5):
        '''
        This functions is used for the purpose of connecting to the UUT
        '''
        global telnet_session
        global connected

        for _ in range(Retry):
            try:
                telnet_session = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, timeout=5)
                connected = True
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                break
            except:
                connected = False
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                continue


    def periodicCall(self):
        """
        Check every 10 sec if there is something new in the queue.
        This is actually Telnet connection status check
        """
        self.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            # This is the brutal stop of the system. You may want to do
            # some cleanup before actually shutting it down.
            import sys
            sys.exit(1)
        self.after(10000, self.periodicCall)


    def processIncoming(self):
        """
        Handle all the messages currently in the queue (if any).
        """
#         global connected

        while self.status_queue.qsize():
            try:
                msg = self.status_queue.get(0)
                # Check contents of message and do what it says
                # As a test, I simply print it
                print(msg)
#                 if not connected:
#                     self.connect_to_uut()
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def workerThread(self):
        """
        This is where we handle the asynchronous I/O.
        """
        global telnet_session
        global connected

        while self.running:
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                telnet_session.sock.send(telnetlib.IAC + telnetlib.NOP)
                connected = True
                msg = 'Connected'
            except:
                connected = False
                msg = 'Disconnected'       #The Actual Status of the Telnet session
                self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")
                if not connected:
                    self.connect_to_uut()

            self.status_queue.put(msg)



class MainScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=30, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=10, weight='bold')

        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                             width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(pady=8)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text="PROGRAM 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(FirstScreen),
                             width=30, font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button2.pack(pady=8)

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg="black")        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")

class FirstScreen(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=10, weight='bold')
        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg='black')        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")
        self.status.bind("<<StatusChange>>", self.statuschange)     # React to the status change event and change the status label accordingly

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainScreen),
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(side="bottom", pady=(0,20))


    def statuschange(self):
        global connected

        if connected:
            self.my_string_var.set('Connected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_ConnectedStyle, fg='springgreen3')
        else:
            self.my_string_var.set('Disonnected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_DisconnectedStyle, fg='red2')

class SecondScreen(tk.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Button_Font_Style1 = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=20, weight='bold')
        self.Status_BasicStyle = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=5, weight='bold')
        self.my_string_var = tk.StringVar()

        self.status = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.my_string_var, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W, font=self.Status_BasicStyle, fg="black")        
        self.my_string_var.set('Connecting...')
        self.status.pack(side="bottom" , fill="x")
        self.status.bind("<<StatusChange>>", self.statuschange)     # React to the status change event and change the status label accordingly

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Main Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainScreen),
                            font=self.Button_Font_Style1, bd=5)
        self.button1.pack(side="bottom", pady=(0,20))


    def statuschange(self):
        global connected

        if connected:
            self.my_string_var.set('Connected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_ConnectedStyle, fg='springgreen3')
        else:
            self.my_string_var.set('Disonnected')
            self.status.config(font=self.Status_DisconnectedStyle, fg='red2')


def main():
    app = BurningApp()        
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, please reduce it to an mvce: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: I have done my best and reduced about 200 lines of code. I would have done better but I was afraid that I would miss some important lines of code

Comment: @MosheS.I guess if you were able to make it work with only one screen then you could make it work with 3 screens too? You just want to update a label.

Comment: My intention was to be as close as possible to the application. I didn't want to fall into to many changes and change the code. It seems like you are right but I thought that it is better for the helpers to have the whole code. This way it only requires you to copy and paste it and try to run it with slight modifications

Comment: _"My intention was to be as close as possible to the application."_ - that should not be your intention. Your intention should be to create a [mcve]. If the problem is with one label and one thread, we don't need most of the other code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley The problem doesn't stand within one label but either with a whole GUI which holds three frames, each includes the status bar. The Telnet status should update to any of the frames (of course only one frame will be raised). The whole picture is important I have the main GUI (with the show_frame) that also includes the threads and the queue methods. Can I miss one of these code blocks in this case ?

Comment: I think you can still reduce these down. There's a lot of code there that is unrelated to the problem. For example, do you really need labels and inputs for the serial number, part number, and hardware version, or can you hard-code those for the purpose of duplicating the problem? Do you really need all five "program" buttons, or  can you reproduce the problem with a single button? And so on.

Comment: It would also be of great benefit if you didn't require an actual telnet to a remote device for the purpose of duplicating the problem. Can't your worker thread just simulate the connection? It can still run in a thread, but unless the fact that you're specifically using telnet is the issue, you can probably make this much easier to duplicate and debug without the overhead of an actual telnet connection.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Can you agree with me that trying to describe my implementation in words without showing the thread management and the status bars will be more difficult and won't help you to help me ?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I understand your point. The widget contents is a lot of noise but that is the contents of my app I will try to reduce it as much as possible without harming the app's functionality. Regarding the Telnet connection, this is the point and it is my problem or at least combining it in my app is the problem. Trying to simulate a mechanism that will update status is more difficult.

Comment: _"I will try to reduce it as much as possible without harming the app's functionality"_ - we don't care about the apps functionality. We only care about being able to reproduce the problem. In fact, the best thing you could do would be to write a brand new, _minimal_ program that has the same problem.

Comment: _"Trying to simulate a mechanism that will update status is more difficult."_ - why? Why can't your functions simply pretend that it got the expected response? Why does reading a string from telnet behave any differently than just sending a hard-coded string?

Comment: Because I can't really tell what is the root cause of my problem. Maybe the Telnet part is buggy and maybey the thread management is buggy. If I could have focus my problem a bit more I w would have done that.

Comment: you have multiple statusbars. How do you know which statusbar you want to update? Or, do you want to update them all? If you want to update them all, why have multiple statusbars? Why not have just one?

Comment: In concept this only one statusbar but I want it to show in the bottom of the screen no matter which frame am I looking at. This is why I added it to each of the frames

Comment: @Bryan Oakley It seems like the custom event that I generate upon Telnet session status change doesn't fire anything. But, I also don't get any exception. I suppose that this is not the way to get an update regarding a status change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally done it, I am able to update the statusbars see the Information below.

I have added the following method in each of the frames. The purpose of this method is to check the flag, that holds the Telnet session status (connect), periodically. So I am still using the same threads: the Main GUI thread and another thread which maintains the Telnet session. In order to "activate" this method I start it once a certain frame was raised ("frame_was_raised" method)

```
def update_statusbar(self):
        '''Poll the Telnet Session Status for the purpose of update'''
        global connected

        if connected:
            self.my_string_var.set('Connected')
            self.status.config(fg='springgreen3')
        else:
            self.my_string_var.set('Disconnected')
            self.status.config(fg='red2')

        self.after(2000, self.update_statusbar)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or are you trying to clarify the question? The answer section should only be used for answers.

Comment: Believe me I know what I am doing, I took the right pills this morning :-)

Comment: Do you mean that, yes, this is an answer? If so, you might want to clarify. For example, maybe the first sentence could be "I solve this by doing the following..." or something like that. As written, it's hard to tell what this information represents.

Answer (score 2):

These adjustment should solve your problem:

```
self.status.config(font=self.Status_ConnectedStyle,
text=self.my_string_var,fg='springgreen3')
```

Comment: I am afraid that the fix has to do with more than you advised. This has something to do with the event management or the threads

Comment: I think the way you are calling the statuschange function may be a problem. Why don't you directly try calling self.statuschange instead of self.event_generate("<<StatusChange>>")

Comment: I would have done exactly what you recommend but my problem is that the trigger for changing the statusbar comes from a different class (and maybe also a different thread)

Comment: Can you please try to create an object of each of the class and then call the method of that class to update your status change whereever necessary

Comment: I don't see the point. Current implementation uses a separate thread for maintaining the Telnet connection. The trigger for a Telnet status change comes from this thread. The steps that you've asked me to do ignore this fact.

Comment: you are binding the statuschange function in the second and first screen class and trying to call the binding from some other class which has no reference to the bindings, how does that materialise?you need to specify it right?

Comment: This is the first time that I am developing an application with GUI and multi-threads. I am completely new to these issues and don't know the rules. I have tried many variations and didn't reach to the final goal. I don't know how to specify it better. Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: to what i understand your code, for each button you press and each time a screen is raised, you want to update the label for that instance, am i right?

Comment: No. My plan is to update the Label only when the Telnet status changes.

Comment: so whenever the telnet status is changed, the label should be updated irrespective of the container that is raised?

Comment: I need the status label to update according to the Telnet status. Because I want this status to be seen no matter which frame is raised then probably I need to update each of the frames. Do you see any problem with this approach ? Can you please suggest a better implementation ?